# Embedding facebook video in react-native app

Tags: facebook, react-native

Is it possible to embed a Facebook video from a public post in a `react-native` app?

If it is possible, I believe I need to use a `<WebView>` component which is what I have used for several other types of video embeds, but the Facebook embed is different.  We have achieved it on our web client, but there are some DOM specific aspects to it that I'm not sure how to recreate in `react-native`.

This is the solution I have used successfully for other video types (e.g. Vine, Vimeo), but for FB it just renders an image

```
<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.facebook.com/TheWitBible/videos/1747642252158297/' }} style={ styles.media } />
```

Here are the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Here is a FB SDK component, but I don't think it supports this use case
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

In the web client there are 2 parts to get it to work

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.6'
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

............................

```
render() {
    return (
      <div ref={el => el && FB && FB.XFBML.parse(el)} className="fb-media-wrapper" style={{ width: this.props.width + 'px' }}>
        <div className="fb-video" data-href={this.props.url} data-width={this.props.width}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked with me

```
<WebView 
 style={styles.yourStyles} 
 source={{ uri: 'https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=<YOUR_ID_VIDEO>'}}  />
```

Comment: this works but the controls doesnt show unless the user presses on the video

Answer (score 0):

I mean this worked totally fine for me

```
<WebView style={{width:350,height:null}} 
 source={{ uri: 'https://www.facebook.com/chris.phillips.56027281/videos/vb.100003747765310/914766415324942?type=2&theater'}}  />
```

Comment: How to prevent play in fullscreen (on iOS) by default?

Comment: Embedding FB videos in a WebView does not work for me. I got a "Sorry, something went wrong" error displayed instead (However, YT works correctly)

Comment: @dfucci check it out https://gist.github.com/alaingoldman/1d90890ec928c55ddcdb4f2b4a11f866 here is how you get it to work, also upvote me :)

Comment: How many could I display on one signe screen? have you tried to load multiple ones?